# How to add data from one ArrayList to another ArrayList using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, shapes

So I have an ArrayList "NamedShape" then i have another ArrayList "Connection" which consists of two fields both being "NamedShape" and i want to add data that i retrieve from the ArrayList "NamedShape" to the ArrayList "Connection"

**Here is my ArrayList "NamedShape"**

```
ArrayList<NamedShape> shapes = new ArrayList<NamedShape>();


public class NamedShape {
    private String name;
    private Shape shape;
    public NamedShape( String name, Shape shape ){
        this.name = name;
        this.shape = shape;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name; 
    }
    public Shape getShape(){ 
        return shape; 
    }
}
```

**And here is my ArrayList "Connection"**

```
ArrayList<Connection> con = new ArrayList<Connection>();

   public class Connection     {
    private NamedShape namedShape1;
    private NamedShape namedShape2;
    public Connection(NamedShape namedShape1,NamedShape namedShape2){
        this.namedShape1 = namedShape1;
        this.namedShape2 = namedShape2;
    }

    public NamedShape getNamedShape1(){
        return namedShape1;
    }
    public NamedShape getNamedShape2(){
        return namedShape2;
    }

    public void setNameShape1(){
        this.namedShape1 = namedShape1;
    }

    public void setNameShape2(){
        this.namedShape2 = namedShape2;
    }
   }
```

So i want to add data that i get from the ArrayList "NamedShape" and add it to the ArrayList "Connection". This is what i've used to retrieve data from the ArrayList "NamedSpace" but to add data to the "Connection" it doesn't work.

```
for(int a=0;a<var;a++) 
{  
Shape s = shapes.get(a).getShape();
String n = shapes.get(a).getName();

// add data to ArrayList "Connection" 
//I've tried this but it does not work.

con.add( new Connection(new NamedShape(con.setNameShape1(n,s))));

}
```

Can you please help me with this?

***EDITED***

So my code below is supposed to allow the user to draw a shape and when the shape is drawn, the user enters the name of the shape which is saved in the array "NamedShape". Then when the size of the "NamedShape is greater than one, it checks for collisions of other shapes with the line. Normally there should be only 2 collisions that is with the start of the line and the end of the line. If collisions exists with the line, it checks if collisions==1, it saved the shape that collides into ArrayList "Connection" under NamedShape1 and if collisions==2, it saved it to that same index but under "NamedShape2" 
Please do what you do best guys!! Help!

```html
if (currentAction == 3) {
                            boolean collision = false;
                            int collisions =0;
                            aShape = drawEllipse(drawStart.x, drawStart.y,
                             e.getX(), e.getY());
                            
                            
                             String text = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(DrawingBoard, "Enter name of Attribute:");
                            if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
                                    text = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(DrawingBoard, "You must enter a valid name!  Please try again:");
                                                                    
                            }
                            else{
                            
                            
                            shapes.add( new NamedShape( text,
                            aShape ) );    
                                                        
                          
                            //returns the coordinates of each rectangle
                            //System.out.println(aShape);
                         int var = shapes.size();
                         System.out.println("Array index"+var);
                         if(var>1){
                            
                            for(int i=0;i<var;i++){ 
                          
                            Shape s = shapes.get(i).getShape();

                           if (s instanceof Line2D) { 
                               
                               System.out.println("Index of line is: "+i);   
                               double x = (s.getBounds2D().getX());
                               double y = (s.getBounds2D().getY());
                               double w = (s.getBounds2D().getWidth());
                               double h = (s.getBounds2D().getHeight());
                               
                          for(int a=0;a<var;a++) {                              
                              Shape f = shapes.get(a).getShape();
                              String nana = shapes.get(a).getName();
                                                           
                                                            
                              if (f instanceof Ellipse2D){
                               double x1 = (f.getBounds2D().getX());
                               double y1 = (f.getBounds2D().getY());
                               double w1 = (f.getBounds2D().getWidth());
                               double h1 = (f.getBounds2D().getHeight());
                               
                               if(s.intersects(x1, y1, w1, h1)){
                                collision = true;
                                collisions ++;
                               if (collisions==1) {    
                                                                    
                              // I want to add data of f and nana from arraylist of NamedShape and adds it
                              //to arraylist connection.
                              // if collsions=1, it adds it to NamedShape1 else if collisions = 2 it add it to NamedShape2
                             
                              //not sure if this will work     
                              con.add( new Connection(new NamedShape(nana, f), new NamedShape(null,null)));
                                                                
                                }
                              
                                System.out.println("Line "+ i +" is linked to "+nana);
                                
                        } 
                               else{
                                collision = false;
                                System.out.println("LINE(E) " + i + "DO NOT COLLIDE WITH ELLIPSE OF INDEX= "+a);
                                
                            }
                                
                              }
                              
                          }                             
                            
                        }       
                      
                        }    
                         }
                            
                            shapeStroke.add(strokeColor);
                            drawStart = null;
                            drawEnd = null;
                            repaint();
                            }
                           
                        }
```

Comment: you have constructor of connection taking two argument but at the time of creating an instance you are sending one attribute of new NamedShape.

Comment: Do you want to generate all the possibile combinations of NamedShape objects?

Comment: Connection constructor takes two arguments but you are only passing one NewShape object, aren't you get a compiling exception?

Comment: @squiroid  What should i do then?

Comment: Can you display the whole of that third code snippet or at least more code for us to make how you created the shapes?

Comment: @Omoro Wait I'll send my codes above right away and may be this will help.

Comment: @Omoro Please see the above edited code.

Comment: @Omoro Please see the above edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate all the combinations among your NamedShape objects you can try with this :

```
for(int i=0; i<shapes.size()-1; i++){
 for(int j=i+1; j<shapes.size();j++){
    conn.add(new Connection(shapes[i],shapes[j]));
}
}
```

Comment: :( it still doesn't work.   I've tried this too but it doesn't work too.   `con.add(new Connection(new NamedShape(con.setNamedShape1(n,s), new NamedShape(con.setNamedShape1(n,s)))));`   Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @LanaM Why doesn't work? What is the Exception thrown? Probably it is `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Try with my edited version.

Comment: @  Fabrizio Morello In fact that's not what am trying to do, i want to copy based on an if statement a specific (index) of NamedShape to Connection.

Comment: @LanaM In this case SMA gave you the right solution, maybe without `set` method. It should be `con.add(new Connection(new NamedShape(n,s), new NamedShape(n,s)));`

Comment: I would like it to add it to a specific location which is NamedShape1. Is that possible?

Comment: Please see the above edited code. Please do your best!

Comment: Please see the above edited code. Please do your best!

Answer (score 1):

Why you are setting NameShape1 object before intiating it n the connection object?

new NamedShape(**con.setNameShape1(n,s)**

Can you try initializing NameShape object and try to pass it to constructur of Connection?

it would be more on the below lines.
con.add( new Connection(new NamedShape("abc", shapObj), new NamedShape("xyz",shapObj)));

or see if you can initialize it in Connection object and one of method returns the given object.

Comment: Sorry i did not understand, what should i do so that the data is put inside the NameShape1? Your second line of code is ok but i want java to write the data to NameShape1 first.

Comment: then just have Connection constructor as public Connection(NamedShape namedShape1){
        this.namedShape1 = namedShape1;
      
    }

Comment: your for loop would be as below if you just want initialize connection object with one NamedShape object.

for(int a=0;a<var;a++) { Shape s = shapes.get(a).getShape(); String n = shapes.get(a).getName();  con.add( new Connection(new NamedShape(n,s))); }

Comment: But in fact i need to have two namedShape, namedShape1 and namedShape2. Wait, i'll send my code above and may be this will help.

Comment: Please see the above edited code, may be this will help to better understand.